# C++ в чём заключается ошибка cannot be used as a function?

Tags: c++, функции

Вроде делал без **bool**, всё работало, сейчас беда какая-то...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

bool chet(int);

void vyvod(int mas[], int a) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        cout << mas[i] << "  ";

    cout << endl;
}

int nechetn(int mas[], int a, int nech[], int u) {
    int i, neb = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (!(chet(mas[i]))) {
            nech[neb] = mas[i];
            neb++;
        }
    }
    return neb;
}

int chetn(int mas[], int a, int ch[], int u) {
    int i, b = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (chet(mas[i])) {
            ch[b] = mas[i];
            b++;
        }
    }

    return b;
}


int main() {
    int i, A, B, chetn, nechetn, kchet, knechetn;
    int mas[30], ch[30], nech[30], chet[30];
    cout << "Диапазон" << endl;
    cout << "введите А: ";
    cin >> A;
    cout << "введите В: ";
    cin >> B;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        mas[i] = rand() % (B - A + 1) + A;

    kchet = chetn(mas, 30, ch, 30);
    knechetn = nechetn(mas, 30, nech, 30);

    cout << "массив рандома: " << endl;
    vyvod(mas, 30);

    cout << "массив четных: " << endl;
    vyvod(ch, kchet);

    cout << "массив не четных: " << endl;
    vyvod(nech, knechetn);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool chet(int a) {
    int i;
    if (a % 2 == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ошибка **где**? В какой строке? Почему в вопросе это указано?

Comment: kchet = chetn(mas, 30, ch, 30);
knechetn = nechetn(mas, 30, nech, 30);
ошибка cannot be used as a function 
и там и там

Comment: В чем назначение переменной `i` в функции `chet`?

Answer (score 5):

Возьмите в привычку давать переменным и функциям **разные** имена. Если вы будете бездумно давать им одинаковые имена - то будут получаться такие ошибки. Это не запрещено, но делать это надо с пониманием происходящего.

У вас в функции `main` имена `chetn` и `nechetn` - это *переменные* типа `int`, а не функции. А вы их пытаетесь "вызывать" как функции. О чем вам компилятор ясно и сказал.

Comment: сейчас другой код отредактирую, там они не объявлены, но ошибка та жа

Comment: @ВасяПупкин Не надо нести чепухи и выдумывать сказки. Так не бывает. Если ошибка "та же" - значит ошибка действительно **та же**.